# Recorrer un array de una consulta en PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo la siguiente función en PHP:

```
function ListarDependencias() {

  $db = new Conexion();
  $sql = $db->query("SELECT Id, Nombre FROM Dependencias;") or die (mysqli_error($db));

  if($db->mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    $result = $db->mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
  } else {
    $result = null;
  }
  $db->liberar($sql);
  $db->close();

  return $result;
}
```

El cual quiero usar para llenar el siguiente select con el siguiente código:

```
<select id="selDependencia" name="selDependencia" class="form-control" required >
   <option value="0"><--Seleccione--></option>
   <?php
     foreach (ListarDependencias() as $dataDependencias) {
       echo "<option value='".$dataDependencias['Id']."'>".$dataDependencias['Nombre']."</option>";
     }
   ?>
```

Tengo solo dos registros en mi tabla, sin embargo me muestra en el select 4 y solo sus primeros caracteres como se muestra la siguiente imagen:

[image: Select]

No quiero tener que traer los scripts de base de datos a mi presentación donde está el select, quisiera poder recorrer el array y mostrar los datos. Así que se agradece cualquier ayuda que pudieran darme. Quizás estoy llamando mal a los valores de mi array que devuelve mi consulta.

Comment: Intenta esto: `$result = $db->mysqli_fetch_all($sql);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hice el cambio que indicaste especificando el tipo de resultado y con eso pude solucionar. Muchas gracias.

```
$result = $db->mysqli_fetch_all($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```